# Will Eclipse 4 have color schemes?

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

I've heard that Eclipse 4 has a completely redone UI, so I'm wondering whether it will (finally!) support color schemes.

Does anybody know?

Comment: Why not ask that question here: http://eclipse.org/ ?

Comment: Note for moderators: this was a perfectly valid question, as [other eclipse color-scheme questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-scheme+eclipse) can attest. The presence of [XWT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/XWT) and CSS themes makes this pertinent for [e4/Eclipse4.0 and Eclipse4.1](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse-dev/msg09064.html), today for the next few years. This question has a lasting value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect some SWT components will still be linked to OS color scheme, but more generally:

- you can apply [eclipse color scheme to e4](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/08/05/eclipse-4-0-so-you-can-theme-me-part-1/)
- there is an **[e4 color scheme repository](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/e4-themes/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Forg.eclipselabs.e4themes%2Fthemes)** for you to explorer

[This article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/08/eclipse4-released) mentions:

> Eclipse 4.0 itself is not using it (XWT) to make up the UI, but translates the EMF-Model in an UI-Representation using the so called Rendering Framework (currently only an implementation based upon SWT exists but there's the possibility to write your own which e.g. use Swing, ...).
>
> The Eclipse 4.0 Application Platform which is the underlying infrastructure for the Eclipse 4.0 SDK doesn't force a developer to use any technology. You are free to use SWT, XWT, Riena, ... to make up your UI.